# Wordpress - Make category.php list posts from subcategories as well

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I'm building a blog where three people will be writing, but they will have a separate section on the site. The structure is built upon categories and looks like this:

- User one

  - Clothes
  - Fashion
  - Life

---

- User two

  - Family
  - Life

---

- User three

  - Family
  - Friends
  - Life

I've set all three users as writers and used the plugin [Restrict Categories](http://wordpress.org/plugins/restrict-categories/) in order to lock their categories to the sub-categories the matching each top level category.

Now here comes the question, if I visit `http://site.example/category/user-one/` I want to have a listing of all the posts, including the sub-categories since there will be no actual content in the top level category that you are browsing.

I've tried making this using filters bound to `pre_get_posts` but I still can't get it to work. Does anyone else here have any ideas?

I've also given some though into actually creating a multisite network for the purpose, but I then realized it will be hard to fetch posts from all the networks at once.

Thanks in advance, Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jonathan: Not sure if I am misinterpreting what you are hoping to achieve, but given that each author will already have their own 'author' page which lists all their posts (if your theme includes this or something you could create or customise), there may not really be a need for Users 1-3 to be their own category?

Going back to your question, for listing subcategories, perhaps  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13485/list-all-subcategories-from-category might be of some help.

As for listing posts, to keep things simple, I reckon you might be able to use e.g. `get_posts` (http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and build custom arguments, perhaps in a loop if you prefer to use one instead of slug/id specific category templates.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

If it's any help, Bainternet actually created a plugin that makes life a little easier to define category templates: http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-category-template/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. You're quite right and I did not think of this to be honest. This would be a perfect approach, but the problem is that I need to have a parent category since two bloggers might both have a category that is called "Family" and if I did not have the parent template their slug would be "family" and "family-2". If I use the author pages the problem is that I need to remove the base so that the site URL is http://site.com/hanna instead of http://site.com/author/hanna. This would work, but it collides with the categories since I removed the base on those as well. Ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can see the conundrum there - if the url is priority, a multisite setup might be preferable.
As for getting posts from sites across the network, this thread might be of help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98965/get-posts-from-sites-in-multisite

These two plugins (not tried them myself) might be able to offer you similar functionality as well:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-posts/
http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-over-network/

And last but not least, this plugin looks rather helpful http://wordpress.org/plugins/multisite-global-search/

Comment: Hello again. I actually managed to get it working by removing the author slug base. This is turn overrides the top category level and returns the author page instead. It's a workaround, while not so pretty it does work like intended and without caveats. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice workaround :) Glad to hear you managed to sort it out - will bear the base thing in mind next time as well.